# Show Error Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

Tags: apex

I have a piece of code that show above error on

```
     d.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
     d.Name = 'Data2'; 
     String myContent = this.name+ '\n ' +this.pass+ '\n ' + this.age+ '\n ' +this.mail; 
     d.body += Blob.valueof(mycontent);
     d.ContentType = 'text/plain';
     d.Type = 'txt';
     upsert d;
     return null;
 }

 d.body += Blob.valueof(mycontent);(Show error in this line)
```

Comment: don't use `+=` try with only `=`

Comment: Hi ratan but i have to append content.

Comment: duplicate http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133380/how-to-combine-multiple-blob-in-apex-to-get-single-blob-value/133381

Comment: Link Dont work for me

Comment: are you sure content append will work this way?

Comment: Let me append without an error after that i tell you.

Comment: Did either of the posted answers work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Blob just doesn't work that way. You need to build up one string, and call `Blob.valueOf` at the end. For instance, you could do:

```
Blob.valueOf(myContent + myContent);
```

Which seems to be what you want in your example. Or, as an alternative to the code in the flagged duplicate:

```
Blob.valueOf('s1' + 's2' + 's3');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append to the Body, you first need to extract the value of the Body Blog as a string so you can append. Try this:

```
Blob firstBlob = Blob.valueOf('test');
String firstString = firstBlob.toString();
Blob secondBlob = Blob.valueOf(firstString + 'test');
System.debug(secondBlob.toString());
```

For a concrete example, try this:

```
Account acct = [SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1];
Attachment attch = new Attachment();
attch.ParentId = acct.Id;
attch.Name = 'Data2';
attch.Body = Blob.valueOf('test');
insert attch;

String blob2String = attch.Body.toString();
Blob secondBlob = Blob.valueOf(blob2String + 'secondtest');
System.debug(secondBlob.toString());

attch.Body = secondBlob;
update attch;
system.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR,attch);
```

This outputs 'testsecondtest' for me.

I'm not sure of what the `d` object is, but I suspect that you should try to catch the error on insert - because it's probably unrelated to the `Blob`

Comment: But that is way less efficient if you already know the string value of `firstBlob`, no?

Comment: Sure, but I think @Bonny to append to an already encoded Body from what they said.

Comment: Right, but my point is that it sounds like `firstString` is already known. That's why I didn't include this approach, anyway. Still, if you didn't already know `firstString`, this would be the way to go, you're right.

Comment: Good point - oh well, bonny now has both options :)

Comment: Hi Casper I did Some changes in my code but its not Append still Here is my Code d.FolderId = UserInfo.getUserId();
         d.Name = 'Data2'; 
         system.debug('d.body==='+d.body);
         String myContent = this.name+ '\n ' +this.pass+ '\n ' + this.age+ '\n ' +this.mail; 
         d.body= Blob.valueof(mycontent); string s1 = d.body.tostring()+mycontent;string s1 = d.body.tostring();
         d.body = blob.valueof(s1); 
         d.ContentType = 'text/plain'; 
         d.Type = 'txt';
         upsert d;
         return null;

Comment: Added a second example for you to try. It should run directly from the execute anonymous window.