# Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

Tags: attachment, blob

The following class will get the content(a maximum of 10 MB) in encode format and I convert the content into decode format based on the my requirement into three parts. Now I want to add the all three blobs into single `Blob` to insert this content into attachment.

But while I am trying to add all three blobs into single blob, It is showing following error.

Even I gone through [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133380/how-to-combine-multiple-blob-in-apex-to-get-single-blob-value). But result comes without success.

> Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

Here is the class:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/stringoncase/*')
        global with sharing class RESTCaseController {
        @HttpPost
        global static String createNewCase(String Casenumber,String filename,String content1,String content2,String content3) {
                Case ca = [Select id,status,Origin from case where casenumber=:Casenumber];
            //ca.Status = status;
            //ca.Origin = web;
            //insert ca;

            blob base1 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content1);
            blob base2 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content2);
            blob base3 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content3);

            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(base1.toString() + base2.toString() + base3.toString());
            attachment.Name = filename;
            attachment.ParentId = ca.id;
            attachment.ContentType='multipart/form-data';//'application/json';
            insert attachment;

            return 'sucess';
        }
    }
```

I provide the input to the class using postman like the following

```
{

        "Casenumber" :"00001060",
        "filename" : "5_MBfiel.pdf",
        "content1" : "------Encoded data------",
        "content2" : "",
        "content3" : ""

}
```

How could I add these three blobs into single Blob?

Comment: I guess you cannot concatenate blob, you need to convert them to string. Before and after split the blob content must not be changed otherwise it would corrupt the data.

Comment: Please edit your question and share some code using which we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @RahulSharma, I modified the question. Please check it.

Comment: I meant how do you pass the parameters, do you do some encoding while calling it from a visualforce? You can get better support when someone can reproduce your error.

Comment: @RahulSharma, I got your question. Now i updated my question again. I give content using rest service.  Please go through it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have in `content1`, `content2`, `content3` Base64 representations of text (not binary content), and assuming you just want to generate an attachment with the concatenation of those 3 strings, you could do the following

```
public class CaseController {
    global static String createNewCase(String Casenumber,String filename,String content1,String content2,String content3) {
        Case ca = [Select id,status,Origin from case where casenumber=:Casenumber];

        blob base1 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content1);
        blob base2 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content2);
        blob base3 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content3);

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(base1.toString() + base2.toString() + base3.toString());
        attachment.Name = filename;
        attachment.ParentId = ca.id;
        insert attachment;
    }
}
```

Assuming that `content1`, `content2` and `content3` are 3 chunks of the SAME valid file, but in Base64 format, you could do...

```
public class CaseController {
    global static String createNewCase(String Casenumber,String filename,String content1,String content2,String content3) {
        Case ca = [Select id,status,Origin from case where casenumber=:Casenumber];

        blob base123 = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(content1 + content2 + content3);

        Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
        attachment.Body = base123;
        attachment.Name = filename;
        attachment.ParentId = ca.id;
        insert attachment;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried as you said, But giving the following error 
`System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string`

Comment: "Assuming that you have in content1, content2, content3 Base64 representations of (UTF-8) text, not binary content". Otherwise you cannot concatenate, because it would make no sense in terms of file structure.